# Can't set color of statusbar with cordova-plugin-statusbar

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, statusbar

I'm trying to change the color of the native status bar in an ionic app, but I can't get it to work. I've installed cordova-plugin-statusbar, and it installs fine. The following code works perfectly:

```
if (StatusBar) {
    StatusBar.hide();
}
```

But trying to use any other of the available functions, for example:

```
if (StatusBar) {
    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHex('#RRGGBB');
}
```

doesn't work, the just app uses the standard statusbar.

I've also added `<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />` to config.xml, as well as setting it programmatically at runtime.

Cordova is version 5.1.1, Ionic is version 1.5.5 and I'm using Android 21 for testing. Has anyone experienced the same problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: try to change your parent activity theme.? in style xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try removing the status bar plugin and reinstalling like so:

```
ionic plugin rm org.apache.cordova.statusbar
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git
```

The same has been reported at the [ionic issue tracker](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-with-status-bar-color/19375)

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. Don't know why that old version would still be available like that.

Comment: Any idea how to get this working with PhoneGap Build? It appears it's also using an old version of the plugin.

Comment: @BenjaminHumphrey - Not sure if you are still experiencing this issue? I am however not too sure how to do this with PG Build. Have you tried installing a different version of the plugin, like so: <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" **version="1.1.0"** />

Comment: I fixed the problem. I wasn't correctly including cordova.js in my index.html file like this: `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`

Comment: This came up again and got fixed on 23 Feb 2017. The same fix as suggested in the answer works again. See commit that was accepted: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/commit/916cccc2c00a1b7c77e2e738c83e74a22bdd55e7

Answer (score 9):

See me original solution at [Can't get cordova-plugin-statusbar to set color on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922115/cant-get-cordova-plugin-statusbar-to-set-color-on-android/35877673#35877673)

Add the plugin. Run shell command:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

Edit your config.xml:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#BE1912" />
```

'#BE1912' is the default color (on app starts).

Change in run time from your java script code:

```
if (window.cordova && StatusBar)
{
    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#BE1912');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Gil's solution doesn't work for me (I've a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge).

```
onDeviceReady: function () {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    console.log(StatusBar);
    if (window.cordova && StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#BE1912');
    }
},
```

Comment: if the device isn't ready, then window.cordova will be undefined