# Can't get cordova-plugin-statusbar to set color on Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429522/cant-set-color-of-statusbar-with-cordova-plugin-statusbar) however I've tried everything and still can't get [cordova-plugin-statusbar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) to work.

I'm using PhoneGap Build to create a PhoneGap / Cordova app. In `config.xml` I have the plugin included like so:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" />
```

And then I have some JavaScript to set the status bar color:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', SetStatusBarColor, false);

function SetStatusBarColor() {
  if (StatusBar) {
    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#4CAF50');
  }
}
```

However, no matter what I do, I can't get the status bar to change color on the phone. PhoneGap is using Cordova version 5.2.0 and my phone has Android 5.1.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the plugin. Run shell command:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

Edit your config.xml:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#BE1912" />
```

'#BE1912' is the default color (on app starts).
Change in run time from your java script code:

```
if (window.cordova && StatusBar)
{
    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#BE1912');
}
```

Comment: One question, where in my project directory would I need to be in on the cmd to run the cordova command?

Comment: at the location of the config.xml file