# Change Android Statusbar color In Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-statusbar

I want to change the Status bar color in Android (I'm using 6.0 for testing). I tried the statusbar plugin and all the solutions I found for it but nothing worked.

This is included in my config.xml `<widget>`:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#BE1912" />
```

My index.js uncludes:

```
if (window.cordova && StatusBar)
{
    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#3399FF');
}
```

Added the plugin per package name and github repo.

Nothing worked so far...

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 6):

Statusbar plugin will work.Remove these lines from config.xml

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#BE1912" />
```

And write `StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#3399FF');` inside `deviceready` like following

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#3399FF');});
```

Comment: Have you written in device ready?Show me the complete JS file.

Comment: You have written two device ready function.Remove all your code.And only write the codes which I posted in the answer.You should write only one device ready function.

Comment: Still not working... And I'm sure it's not because of my device, because it works on other apps. This is the only code I have: `document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#3399FF');});`

Comment: Refer to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429522/cant-set-color-of-statusbar-with-cordova-plugin-statusbar

Answer (score 4):

I just included the following preferences in config.xml and is working now:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#5b2e90" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

Comment: not working for me.. `<widget ...><your code>...</widget>`

Answer (score 1):

**Mention the below code in index.html( app's starting page )**
**Note**:- No need to mention in entire  Cordova Application , Just mention in the index.html ( app's starting page )

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function () {
             document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 


        });

        function onDeviceReady() {

            StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
            StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#333"); // => #333333

             StatusBar.styleLightContent();
            console.log(statusbar);

        }
</script>
```