# Status Bar color does not work

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Status Bar color does not work.

```
 statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#13204c");
```

I'm using ionic 3.

---

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen:

SplashScreen) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {

      statusBar.styleDefault();
      statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#13204c");

      splashScreen.hide();
}
```

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private sqlite: SQLite) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      //statusBar.styleDefault();
      statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#13204c");

      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/38169172/4826457

Comment: The lines reported in the link article do not exist in our config.xml file.

Comment: What Android version are you using?
According to this post, changing the color is only supported from Android 5.0.
Had the same issue because my emulator was on 4.4.2.

Comment: Forgot to insert the link to my source: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-with-status-bar-color/19375/2

Comment: I'm using android 5.0.1

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Does this.statusBar.hide() work? Note that I'm also accessing the statusBar with this.statusBar. Can you show the full file?

Comment: Did not solve.  =( No error in console.

Comment: I'm using the crosswalk, does that mean anything?

Comment: I haven't worked with crosswalk yet but it doesn't look like it would interfere with the statusbar. It's weird enough that you don't get any errors in the console. Please try to use access modifiers in the constructor (like private statusBar: StatusBar) for all arguments and the access them with this.statusBar and so on. Can you confirm that you get into the this.platform.ready().then() block at all? Does this.statusBar.hide() work?

Comment: this.statusBar.hide() Yes, work.

Comment: I updated every ionic 3.3.0 library and now it worked. Thank you Tobias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated every ionic 3.3.0 library and now it worked.